# How to get events in shared memory in client-server application

Tags: c++, client-server, shared-memory

I am trying to use shared memory for my client server application. I am using File mapping concept for it. Server is going to create file map using CreateFileMapping API. Then it will use `MapViewOfFile` and copymemory api to copy for the shared space.

Client is going to open the same File mapping and reading from the shared space.
The code is working fine But as per my requirements server is going to put data continuously and client is going to read data.

I need help if I use `while` as per the code below it is working but it is taking a huge CPU cycles about 90 percent.

Here is my client code :

```
while (1)
{
    pBuf = (WCHAR *)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        1024);

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not map view of file (%d) \n", GetLastError());

        //CloseHandle(hMapFile);

        getchar();

        return 1;
    }
    if (wcslen(pBuffCheck) == 0)
    {
        wcscpy(pBuffCheck, pBuf);
        //printf("\n File From the Server Found %ls", pBuffCheck);
    }
    else
    {
        if (wcscmp(pBuf, pBuffCheck) != 0)
        {
            wcscpy(pBuffCheck, pBuf);
            printf("\n File Path %ls", pBuffCheck);
        }
    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
    //CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    pBuf = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronise write and read operations across server and client instead of wasting CPU time in unwanted reads.

Think of using named manual reset event (CreateEvent) and WaitForSingleObject to synchronise between writes and reads inside the while loop across processes.